# NU1605 warning for different version of EF Core in dependency project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nuget

We have project "Purchases" which uses Entity Framework Core version 2.2.
In this project we want to use another project "Audit" which uses newer version of Entity Framework Core (5.0.13)

```
"Purchases"  -> "EF Core" (2.2)
            |
             -> "Audit" -> "EF Core" (5.0.13)
```

After adding reference of "Audit" project to the "Purchases" build fails with the error:

> Detected package downgrade: 'EntityFrameworkCore' from 5.0.13 to 2.2. Reference
> the package directly from the project to select a different version.

This seems like exact scenario described in the example 1 from [NuGet Warning NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605)

We can not upgrade EF Core version in "Purchases" project at this moment.

Question: How we can use "Audit" project in other projects with older EF Core versions?

Comment: Use a version of audit that uses EF Core 2

Comment: Does that mean dependency project aren't allow to use different(newer) version of own dependencies? If so is this NuGet limitation or .NET dynamic library linking?